# Polymer redux state undefined property

Tags: javascript, redux, polymer, state

Inside of my element I can access my state via statePath without a problem.

But when I try it inside a function I get undefined.
but I can dump state object with correct values to console.

```
const state = this.getState();
console.log(state.User); // undefiend
console.log(state); // I can see User with value as JSON
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show us exactly what `console.log(state)` prints.

Comment: structReducer: Object {authenticated: undefined, User: "Jhon", Name: "HEY"}
__proto__: Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}

Comment: if I use "state.structReducer.User" then it is working , so is this the normal behavior in Redux. My reducer function has it is own object domain in global state object ?